# How did this user get so much change?

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

I checked a user's profile, but I do not see a lot of questions. I am curious; how did they earn so much change?

[image]

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2023-01-01/20576394#20576394

Comment: That's the user's change in rank from the prior year.

Comment: Last year they made 45 rep and were ranked at the rank #343246. This year they made 1454 rep and are now at rank #3160. That's an improvement of ~340k ranks.

Comment: There is *definitely* a duplicate somewhere, either here and/or on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: I think we can conclude that in a site such as Stack Overflow, that +339000 change difference actually is not to be considered a lot, it is pretty normal :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Last year, the user was on position 343246 in the ranking](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2022-01-01/20576394?sort=reputationchange#20576394) with 45 reputation for the year and 52 total reputation.

This year, they've gathered 1454 reputation which earned them 3160 place. Thus you see the relative change from last year in ranking. Considering the *vast majority of low ranks* (low in the list - higher *numbered* ranks) are accounts with almost no to literally no activity, it does not take much to surpass them in ranking.

With that said, I am not sure why the numbers do not add up:

342509 (last ranking) - 339349 (the change) = 3897 (the supposed new position)

Which does not fit. Also:

3160 (the current position) + 339349 (the change) = 342509 (what the old position is supposed to be)

The numbers might be cached and pending a recalculation.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/